# Getting Error SVN E195012 unable to find repository

Tags: svn, repository

When I am trying to read from my repository (SVN) I am getting an error

> svn: E195012: Unable to find repository location for 'https://www.SVNURL.com/path/to/my/file' in revision 409123

Why am I getting this?

I am trying to use SVN command line interface to read it from the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the path 'path/to/my/file' has been changed before the revision 409123 had been made. 
One possible way in that case is to get correct path of the revision and then try to execute the svn command. For example, if you are intending to read the "file", you won't success with following due to the reason.

```
svn cat -r 409123 https://www.SVNURL.com/path/to/my/root/file
```

But you may find the path before it had been changed in this way.

```
svn info -r 409123 https://www.SVNURL.com/path/to/my/root/
```

After you find the actual path, say that is "/path/to/previous/root/", then you can read the file like following.

```
svn cat -r 409123 https://www.SVNURL.com/path/to/previous/root/file
```